# JAXB Generate Java from XSD with multiple imports

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to build java classes out of these `xsd` schema.

I have 4 `xsd` schemas: `base.xsd`, `lawsuitcontext.xsd`, `security.xsd` and `digitalfile.xsd`:

`digitalfile.xsd` has references to `base`, `lawsuitcontext` and `security` namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/digitalfile"
    xmlns:base="http://example.com/base"
    xmlns:lawsuitcontext="http://example.com/lawsuitcontext"
    xmlns:security="http://example.com/security"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/digitalfile"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://example.com/base" />
    <import namespace="http://example.com/lawsuitcontext" />
    <import namespace="http://example.com/security" />
        ....
</schema>
```

`base.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/base"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/base" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
        ....
</schema>
```

`lawsuitcontext.xsd` references to `base` and `security` namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/lawsuitcontext" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/lawsuitcontext" 
    xmlns:base="http://example.com/base/integration"
    xmlns:security="http://example.com/security" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    
    <import namespace="http://example.com/base" />
    <import namespace="http://example.com/security" />
        ....
</schema>
```

`security.xsd` references to `base` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/security"
    xmlns:base="http://example.com/base" 
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/security"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    
    <import namespace="http://example.com/base" />
        ....
</schema>
```

In every schema there are many types which are used from another schema.

That's `catalog.cat`:

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
         "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">

<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">                
    <public publicId="http://example.com/base" uri="base.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="http://example.com/lawsuitcontext" uri="lawsuitcontext.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="http://example.com/security" uri="security.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

I tried following command:

```
xjc -d out -catalog catalog.cat digitalfile.xsd
```

It gives error that's not possible to resolve element from `base.xsd`

```
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'base:Request' to a(n) 'type definition' component.                                                         line 640 of file:/C:/example/digitalfile.xsd
```

So question is how correctly call `xjc` to build classes that all imports will be resolved and types redefinition will be prevented? Which kind of binding/catalog will be necessary?